# fill a array with foreach in foreach javascript (angular)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, foreach

I have categories. and each category has items. now i return a category list and a item list from the api.

now in angular i want to make this into 1 object. I have done the following:

```
        if ($scope.categories_norm) {
            $scope.delivery_items = [];

            //get categories
            angular.forEach(data.item_categories.normal_categories, function (v, k) {
                //push categories
                $scope.delivery_items.push(v);

                //push items for categories
                var i = 0;
                if ($scope.items) {
                    angular.forEach($scope.items, function (val, key) {
                        i++;
                        if (val.item_category_id == v.item_category_id) {
                        //console.log();
                            $scope.delivery_items[k][i].push(val);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
```

for some reason i can not fill this. it returns errors:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

how must i do this the proper way? I want a object inside each category object with all items

Comment: which line is it erroring on?

Comment: $scope.delivery_items[k][i].push(val);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the `k` in `$scope.delivery_items[k][i].push(val);` change it to `v` and see what happens.

EDIT:

Ok, after looking at your question again, I thought this might work better:

```
if ($scope.categories_norm) {
        $scope.delivery_items = {}; // create empty object
        //get categories
        angular.forEach(data.item_categories.normal_categories, function (v, k) {
            var catagery = v.category_name; // create cataogry variable scoped to this block
            $scope.delivery_items[category] = {}; //create empty category object using category name as the key
            if ($scope.items) {
                angular.forEach($scope.items.filter(check_item_category(v.item_category_id)), function (val, key) {
                    $scope.delivery_items[category][category_info] = v; // comment out or omit this line if you don't want category information included within the category
                    $scope.delivery_items[category][val.item_name] = val; // set item object to it's corosponding name
            });
        };
    });
}

function check_item_category (category_id) {
    return function(item) {
        return item.item_category_id == category_id
    }
}
```

You're still going to have to fill in bits of it (namely how to get the category and item names) but that should be what you want.

EDIT: I switched to using a filter, I just didn't like seeing the id check for each item, I think using a filter would just be cleaner.

EDIT:

It should end up with an object like this:

```
{
    "category_1" : {
        "category_info" : category_object,
        "item_1" : item_1_object,
        "item_2" : item_2_object
    }
    "category_2" : {
        "category_info" : category_object,
        "item_1" : item_1_object,
        "item_2" : item_2_object,
        "item_3" : item_3_object,
    }
    "category_3" : {
        "category_info" : category_object,
        "item_1" : item_1_object,
        "item_2" : item_2_object,
        "item_3" : item_3_object,
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Ok, one last time, I looked at this again and realised this could be made faster (reducing the times `$scope.items` is iterated over ) and at the same time will remove duplication of data (the item's name being in both the key and the item object).

Please note however you won't store the category object along with the category should you use this solution

```
if ($scope.categories_norm) {
        $scope.delivery_items = get_items_sorted_by_category(data.item_categories.normal_categories,$scope.items) // create empty object
    });
}

function get_items_sorted_by_category(categories,items) {
    var filled_object = {}
    for(var category in categories){
        //will need to change how you set the catagory name as I don't know how this object looks
        filled_object[category.name] = items.filter(check_item_category(category.item_category_id)) // will filter out any objects that don't have the correct caragory ID
    };
    return filled_object;
}

function check_item_category (category_id) {
    return function(item) {
        return item.item_category_id == category_id
    }
}
```

you should get an object that looks like this:

```
{
    "category_1" : [
        "item_1", 
        "item_2", 
        "item_3"
    ]
    "category_2" : [
        "item_1",
        "item_2",
        "item_3"
    ]
    "category_3" : [        
        "item_1",
        "item_2",
        "item_3"
    ]
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined .. on that line

Comment: i dont get this solution. items are also objects with multiple data in them

Comment: How you were using the array before was just funky, it didn't sit right or look right, this way you create an organised object; using the category name as a key for an object that's then filled with item names as keys for an object containing said item's info. Have a look at the answer for an example object.

Comment: now im getting: ReferenceError: item_category_id is not defined with your code on: thi sline angular.forEach($scope.items.filter(check_item_catagory(item_category_id,v.item_category_id)), function (val, key) {

Comment: Right, sorry made a mistake, filter's a tricky one, to get the call back to accept  an extra value (the category id), you need to create a function that takes a value (the category id) and then returns the actual call back which also takes a value (the item from the array) and then compares that item's id against the category id supplied from earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Remove '[i]'

```
    if ($scope.categories_norm) {
        $scope.delivery_items = [];

        //get categories
        angular.forEach(data.item_categories.normal_categories, function (v, k) {
            //push categories
            $scope.delivery_items.push(v);

            //push items for categories
            var i = 0;
            if ($scope.items) {
                angular.forEach($scope.items, function (val, key) {
                    i++;
                    if (val.item_category_id == v.item_category_id) {
                    //console.log();
                        $scope.delivery_items[k].push(val);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Or remove 'push':

```
    if ($scope.categories_norm) {
        $scope.delivery_items = [];

        //get categories
        angular.forEach(data.item_categories.normal_categories, function (v, k) {
            //push categories
            $scope.delivery_items.push(v);

            //push items for categories
            var i = 0;
            if ($scope.items) {
                angular.forEach($scope.items, function (val, key) {
                    i++;
                    if (val.item_category_id == v.item_category_id) {
                    //console.log();
                        $scope.delivery_items[k][i] = val;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: a had done both already, when i remove push "TypeError: Cannot set property '9' of undefined" and when i push without i "TypeError: undefined is not a function"